# Exporting models with Papyrus

Tags: papyrus

I am a newby to Papyrus.  Export seems to only support exporting graphics of the model diagrams.  Is there a way to export a model that is compatibly with other tools, such as XMI?

Comment: Interested in the same question. Thinking to use papyrus for the http://openmockup.net project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an XMI file for your model by doing the following:

1. Right click on the project containing the model you wish to export
2. Select General > File System
3. Include the .uml file for the model to export
4. Select the directory for export and click Finish